# Can Civi/WordPress an Civi/Drupal (same versions) share a database?

Tags: wordpress, drupal, import

This would make it a lot easier to manage a transition between an existing Drupal site and a new WordPress site. In my case, all core programs and the existing databases are on the same server. It would sure be nice to just configure the new WP Civi to look at the old Drupal Civi database.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the database table can be shared between the two sites. However, there will/might be an issue with the WP user table and the drupal user table with the civicrm_uf_match table. One potential option might be to ensure that the user ids across wordpress and drupal dont conflict, i.e. choose a high starting point for the WP user table (which is a manual process in mysql)

Comment: Thanks, Lobo. This will make life a lot easier. Does this really matter if the WP users and the Drupal users are the same?

Comment: no, but i do think it is super important that the user ids dont conflict. if they do, u r likely to get a mysql foreign key constraint error

Comment: Thanks, again. Since I have only two users on the WP Sandbox, I'll look into how to make all the Drupal user IDs compatible.

Comment: The shared DB sort of worked until WordPress did an automatic MySQL version update and Drupal didn't. This resulted in an error message about versions not matching, which I interpreted to mean the content was mismatched, not the version number. An attempt to separate the two DBs and upload a backup to the Drupal DB crashed midway and  now I get an error message about a partial DB and recommending I get the ISP to restore from backup. Unfortunately the backup we used was also, apparently, a partial. So if anyone wants to try the shared DB routine, make sure to turn off Automatic Updates in WP.

Comment: We looked into this - what Lobo suggests does indeed mean you can get Wordpress & Drupal sharing a CiviCRM database, but ultimately each user can have only one uf match. 

So in practical terms for us that meant that when users logged into Drupal (original site) and filled out a form, their details would pre-populate.  When they logged into Wordpress (new site) their details wouldn't pre-populate until we flushed the civicrm_uf_match table and linked all the records to Wordpress accounts (which of course creates a problem for Drupal)